# Gitlab CI Display times in job log

Tags: time, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, jobs

Is there a way to display times in Gitlab CI in the job log?

---

As shown in the image below, for some commands (I guess automated setup commands) there are times shown on the right.

[image: Screenshot of Gitlab CI Job log]

Is there a way to show these times on custom script commands?

I know that I can use e.g. `bash`s [`date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command. But this does not show the time difference from the initialization time plus does not look that good. Also the time-displays are present already somewhere, so I wonder if they can be used directly.

Comment: I've never seen a way other than manually adding `date` commands to my scripts. If you're a paying customer, contacting your sales rep is a good way to kickstart additional dev work on it, but the current time log took almost 4 years to implement. In the issue that added that time log, someone mentioned adding it for each command in the script sections, but it wasn't picked up. [Here's](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/63880) the initial Issue if you want to read further.